# SimpleDateFormat ambiguous matching

Tags: java

I have the code:

```
public List<Date> parse(String date) {
        // todo: for parsing
        List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf.setLenient(true);
        for (String format: DATE_FORMATS) {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            try {
                Date dt = sdf.parse(date);
                System.out.println("Success! "+format);
                dateList.add(dt);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //System.err.println("failed!");
            }
        }
        return dateList;
    }
```

which is called:

```
parse("Monday Aug 29 5:51 PM GMT 2016")
```

I am getting the results:

```
Success! EEEE MMM dd hh:mm a z yyyy
Success! EEEE MMM yyyy hh:mm a z dd
```

Why does the second pattern match the example? Any enlightenment would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide items of DATE_FORMATS .

Comment: You are printing out `DATE_FORMATS`. Add it to the code so we can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your bellow code will overridden by new object creation.

```
sdf.setLenient(true);
```

object creation after modifying attribute.(useless above line due to bellow)

```
 sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);//replace this code by applyPattern
```

Now Lenient will again have default value.

instead of that use method like bellow to dynamically set pattern to sdf

```
sdf.applyPattern(arg0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using lenient date formats, which allow out of range date elements.  If you don't want out of range elements to be allowed, use non-lenient date formats.

For example, this code only parses with one of the date formats provided:

```
  public List<Date> parse(String date) {
    // todo: for parsing
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String format: DATE_FORMATS) {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
      sdf.setLenient(false);
      try {
        Date dt = sdf.parse(date);
        System.out.println("Success! "+format);
        dateList.add(dt);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //System.err.println("failed!");
      }
    }
    return dateList;
  }
```

I believe the second format is parsing the supplied date as the 2016th day of August 0029 when in lenient mode.

Comment: Also worth noting that the first `setLenient` in the OP's code is ignored anyways, since `sdf` is reinitialized in the loop, but that's pretty moot since a) it's ignored and b) the default is `true` anyways.

Comment: @JasonC, yes, indeed.